# Size of uploaded image is 0 while using php

Tags: php

I am trying to upload images to the server, The image is successfully uploaded to both my images folder and SQL database, but the image size is 0. I am using postman to upload the image and in the future, I will use this script to upload images from android. Below is my PHP script. Thank You

```
$con = mysqli_connect($host_name, $user_name, $user_pass, $db_name);

$filename = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$productname = $_POST['productname'];
$storename = $_POST['storename'];

$upload_path = "ecomerceimage/$productname.$filename";


$sql = "INSERT INTO `imageinfo` (`id`, `image`, `storename`, `productname`) 
 VALUES (NULL, '$filename', '$storename', '$productname');";
 

 if(mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
    file_put_contents($upload_path, base64_decode($filename));
    echo json_encode(array('response' => "Image uploaded successfylly"));
 }else{
    echo json_encode(array('response' => "Image upload failed"));
 }
 mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: You've tagged [[tag:sql-server]] and [[tag:mysqli]] here; these tags conflict. MySQLi is a PHP library for MySQL, it doesn't work with SQL Server. The syntax you have (using backticks (`\``) for delimit identifiers) suggests you are using MySQL, not SQL Server here.

Comment: **WARNING:** Your code is **dangerous**. It is wide open to SQL injection attacks. Always, *always, **always*** parametrise your code. [Why do we always prefer using parameters in SQL statements?](//stackoverflow.com/q/7505808)

Comment: Removed the conflicting database tags, feel free to add the single correct one back.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this would work or not, But I think you're decoding the name only, you should decode the image instead of name.

```
if(mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
    file_put_contents($upload_path, base64_decode($image));
```